# How to create horizantal scrollable tabbar bar in android?

Tags: android, tabbar

[image]

[image]

I would like to create tabbar as shown in the image how can i do it in androidwith arrow when the opitions are more then four how it is possible in android?

As shown in the second screen when the user presses the right side arrow button other opitions are appear how can i write code for this please help me regard this...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want something more complicated than just scrolling tabs with arrows you can wrap  your *TabWidget* by *HorizontalScrollView* and *LinearLayout*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    params="...">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout>
                 <ImageView
                     params="..."/>
                 <HorizontalScrollView
                     params="...">
                      <TabWidget
                          params="..." />
                 </HorizontalScrollView>
                 <ImageView
                     params="..."/>
            </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            params="..." />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And in code you should set *OnScrollListener* for *HorizontalScrollView* to disappear ImageView of arrows

Comment: What error? I write this code here, so i could made some syntax errors, but I did exactly this structure in my project and it works fine

Comment: Now it is working fine.I want to show the user as i mentioned in the above figure when the user presses the right side arrow it needs to move and in the left side also i need to show the arrow,when all are completed in the right side the arrow need not visible.

Comment: just set `onScrollChanged` for HorizontalScrollView and if there is possibility to scroll right or left - change visibility of `ImageViews`

Comment: As i shown in the first figure i should show like the first image when the user presses the right side arrow the menu should move left side then show the left side arrow after finishing all the items at rightside the rightside arrow should not show.

Comment: If we set the onscrollchaged for Horizontalscrollview we need to touch that menu i need when the user click the arrow at that time need to move my menu bar.

Comment: Practice shows that users will never click on that arrows - they are too small for finger

Comment: Great thought..Thanks for your suggestion.And Thanks a lot for solving my problems.Can i know u r mail id.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5771/discussion-between-new-to-android-development-and-jin35)

Comment: Yes, I use it in app with minSdkVersion = 7